# String Formatting from Scanner

Tags: c#, string-formatting

Hi guys i have been trying various methods to fix this, but i can think of none im hoping someone can help me

My scanner gives me a string in the format 0000 to display weight i need to turn this into 00.00 or 0.00 i have tried stuff like this

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", data);
```

as well as converting it to decimal then trying this

```
data.ToString("0.00");
```

All of my attemps all end it showing like this my data is 0500 it then ends up as 500.00 '

can someone give me a suggestion please

final code

```
var data4 = data3.Insert(2, ".");
string data5 = double.Parse(data4).ToString("F", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
label8.Text = data5;
```

Comment: is it always 4 letters long? you can just do `string.Insert(2, ":")` if thats the case, otherwise `string.Insert(string.Length - 2, ":")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [predefined string formatters in .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx), in this case **F** for fixed-point:

```
var s = "0000";
System.Console.WriteLine(double.Parse(s).ToString("F", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")));
s = "0750".Insert(2,",");
System.Console.WriteLine(double.Parse(s).ToString("F", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")));
```

The output would be:

```
0.00
7.50
```

You could also format the string directly using [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx):

```
string.Format("{0:F2}", s, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

The output would be:

```
07,50
```

Comment: i tried the "F" and it still returned 500.00 for some reason, i dont no where the other guys answer went, data3.Substring(0, 2) + "." + data3.Substring(2) works, but i was kinda hoping i could make it 5.00 or 0.40 or 11.00  depending

Comment: @quatre432 This is interesting - in my case it worked without further changes. Anyway, insert the decimal point (**,** or **.** - depending on the culture) before formatting with **F**.

Comment: i gotcha that make sense now sorry it took me a minute

Comment: also can you tell me why when i put your name it doesnt show after i hit enter everyone tells me to put @personname in my comment but it doesnt stay

Comment: Because since you are adding a comment to *my* answer, i always will be informed and it doesn't make sense to add me as a recipient. It makes sense if you want to address not the author of the answer. Glad that the solution worked for you.